# Code to replace the URL of image automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

Need your help in JavaScript # Loading an image automatically without actually changing the url by hand again and again. My code is below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var rows = 4, columns = 4;
    load(rows,columns,"http://i.computer-bild.de/imgs/wallpaper/6/1/5/5/7/8/0/Neckartal-650x488-6e1eb7a79f41a7ff.jpg");
```

this is a part of the javascript code that I am working on. I am in need of the code in which we can open gallery on phone and the (chosen )image's storage location should replace the previous link when we choose a photo/image from the gallery. It is difficult to actually paste the image location manually again and gain. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I didn't figure out any other way other than manually changing the url

Comment: Can you post all of your code?

Comment: https://codepen.io/123456789012345/pen/ZxPqRG       This is the link to the ciode. I could not post the entire due to the space constraints on SO